# How can I reverse certain letters in a string using excel function

Tags: excel, string, function, excel-formula, reverse

I have a very simple request, please help.

Currently I have the following string in excel "17-May-10", and I need it to be "10-May-17". So as you can see just reverse the 17 and 10. Can someone let me know how to do this by only using excel functions? Thanks in advance!

G

Comment: Is really a string?  Or is it a date formatted to look like a string?

Comment: Try changing the format of the cell to `dd-mmm-yy` and see if it changes, if not it is a string that needs to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make actual change and not just visual:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","@",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))))&"-"&MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","@",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")))))-FIND("-",A1)-1)&"-"&LEFT(A1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `REPLACE`

`=REPLACE(REPLACE(A2,1,2,(RIGHT(A2,2))),(LEN(A2)-1),2,LEFT(A2,2))`

see this example:
[image: Using REPLACE]

---

data used:

```
input       output
17-May-10   10-May-17
```

Answer (score 0):

This one formula would work for both the cases, when the date is entered as a string or as a date itself,

`=TEXT(A1,"yy-mmm-dd")`

**As Date:**

[image]

**As String:**

[image]